# How to count CPU Usage of multiprocess application in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, apache, multiprocess

I try to make a program with C/C++, to behave like top command in Linux.
I've done some research and already known how to count CPU Usage of a process. We can get the CPU Usage by calculating stime + utime from /proc/[PID]/stat in current time and after several seconds. Then calculate the stime + utime differences and divide the result with uptime differences to, then we get the CPU Usage percentage. It will be so easy on single process/multithread process.

The problem is in the case like httpd, where it works as multiprocess. When the webserver busy, httpd will fork child processes to serve bunch of requests. Then I count the number of total process, let's say 500. I want to calculate the CPU Usage of those processes, but summarize them so I only see 1 httpd CPU Usage. But if I do the algorithm like I've mentioned above, when the number of processes decrease into < 500 after several seconds, I get the negative values, since the calculation will be like this (for example, I choose random number, just to give you brief description):

```
Uptime: 155123, No of processes : 500, Stime + Utime total of 500 processes : 3887481923874
Uptime: 155545, No of processes : 390, Stime + Utime total of 390 processes : 2887123343874
```

If you look the the example above, the delta of Stime + Utime will results in negative value, since the number of process decreasing, and give the lower value after few miliseconds. I just want to know, is there any other way to calculate such process behave like this? Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the set of processes? By its process group? By the name of the program?

Comment: First, I get the main parent process. I know that because it has ppid 1 and let's say its pid 1227. Then, search the whole /proc/ directory, which has ppid 1227. If the /proc/pid1/stat has ppid 1227, then I add its utime and stime to 1227 utime and stime.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest keeping the data for each process separately.
When you have a new sample, each process may fall in one of three categories:
1. Existed both before and after - subtract old from new.
2. Exists now, but not before - just take the new values.
3. Existed before, but not now - ignore it. You're missing something here, because it may have used CPU during 90% of your sample period, but I hope you don't need perfect accuracy.

It makes you keep more data between samples, and requires using a more complicated data structure, but it should give reasonable results.

Comment: Yeah, I think that will solve the problem, but cost some complex work. I'll try to keep TOP 200 PID which exist long enough, and keep subtracting them until one gets 0 and replace it with the newcomer. The subtraction will then be added to a container, which will be mixed with the newcomer. I think I should try that one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need accurate result or if life time of processes are short, then you must read time usage of a process when it is terminated.

There is atleast two ways:

1) Use `wait4(2)` or `wait3(2)` functions to wait process termination. Those functions will return utime and stime of the process.

2) Keep terminated processes in zombie state until reading of `/prox/<pid>/stat`.